# ASP .NET MVC - How to use token from OAuth Sign In with future REST calls

Tags: asp.net-mvc, oauth, owin

I have an ASP .NET MVC application (default template).

I have added a Nuget package for OAuth support for an external provider.

I have successfully logged in with the external provider, however I now need to use the token that they provide to make REST calls with another API I am using.

How do I get the token the external provider has given?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should refer to the external provider's docs to see how you can get the token. For the ASP.NET's own identity you call %appurl%/token and then store it somewhere like in your session and then send it in your authorization header as described here.
http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/security/individual-accounts-in-web-api

For most providers it should work because ASP.NET itself works with the token of let's say facebook and generates a token for you itself so you always use yourapplication/token to get the token.

See this question
[MVC 5 Web API with Facebook access token to RegisterExternal without need of Cookie](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27754171/mvc-5-web-api-with-facebook-access-token-to-registerexternal-without-need-of-coo)

Comment: So you have to make another call - it's not already stored from the initial authorise?  Their docs don't explicitly say but they do reference: `https://externalsite.com/1/OAuthGetAccessToken` - so I have to make another call to that?

Comment: Yes in order to get the token, no matter if you use individual database accounts or an account from an auth provider like FB/MS/Google you should call /token to get the token. 
You should not put this in a cookie to be sent automatically as well because it will create security wholes. Web API's security part at www.asp.net/web-api has good descriptions for all of this. Read the stuff there and you'll have a solid foundation.