# What is the MVC "way" to do additional logic in external authentication/login?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, facebook, asp.net-mvc-5, owin

Consider the following scenario:

On MVC 5 (or higher), you have enabled 3rd party authentication (e.g. Facebook, Google).

As part of the authentication process, we want to perform an additional operation with the 3rd party authentication provider -- e.g. Facebook check if the logging-in user has liked a particular page, or if the user's email address is pre-approved/white-listed somewhere.

The cycle of events seems like it should be:
1. Authenticate user via external service (e.g. get user-id/email and 3rd party uniqueID)
2. Use 3rd party uniqueID (e.g. Facebook Id #) to perform queries to get some information about the user
3. If the user matches some criteria, sign-in user; if not return to login screen

To me, it seems like there should be a method we can override in the the authentication process like this that would do the trick:

(This hypothetical example of what I'm looking for covers checking the property of the user in the normal login-in cycle -- we'll get to doing additional 3rd party querying in a second).

```
override Boolean BeforeReturnSignedInUser(AppUser user){

if (whitelistedUsers.Email.Contains(user.email)){
    return true;
}

else {
     return false;
}
```

Similarly, it seems like there should be a way to access the 3rd party accessToken fairly easily to perform additional logic against the 3rd party social media graph, but it seems like, according to this, not: [MVC 5 Web API with Facebook access token to RegisterExternal without need of Cookie](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27754171/mvc-5-web-api-with-facebook-access-token-to-registerexternal-without-need-of-coo)

(On the other hand, this is more encouraging: [How to access Facebook private information by using ASP.NET Identity (OWIN)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18942196/how-to-access-facebook-private-information-by-using-asp-net-identity-owin) but still requires adding a lot of artifacts for what should be a pretty simple operation)

In any event, neither of these examples seem clean -- seems like adding a lot of complexity to do an additional check that is all of 5 lines of code!

Answer (score 0):

The MVC way to do this is to configure the facebook middleware to grab the info you want in the `ConfigureAuth` method in `Startup.Auth.cs` (I'm looking at the MVC5 project template), then add any custom claims you want in `IdentityModels.cs` (it even has a comment `// Add custom user claims here`). This avoids clashes that would occur if you try to add claims elsewhere.

Comment: Looks like one has to specify a custom IFacebookAuthenticationProvider.

Comment: Okay, so I see how you get the access token from the FacebookAuthenticatedContext.

Comment: However, I still don't see in the sign-in life-cycle where I could cancel the sign-in if additional criteria aren't met.  (I do see how you could store such data by registering an object via app.CreatePerOwinContext, but I don't see where I would read the data and prevent sign-in if criteria isn't met).

Comment: hmm. In the MVC template external logins are validated in `ExternalSignInAsync` method of the `ApplicationSignInManager` class. Unfortunately this is non-virtual so can't be overridden to add additional validation logic.

Comment: So my thinking is it should be possible to configure it to get the info in Startup.Auth (see: http://www.oauthforaspnet.com/providers/facebook/) then in the `ExternalLoginCallback` of the `Account` controller, that info should be available in the `loginInfo` object so you could do the validation logic there.